# Long polling using Xampp

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, xampp, long-polling

I've a webpage, which sets up ssh connection to linux host and executes the script. I'd like to long poll the result which are being run on the linux host.

I'm using Xampp as a localhost server.

Here's my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

$(sub).click(function(){ 

    alert("connecting to host")
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'/cgi-bin/rfc.py', 
                async: false ,
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success:function (data) {
                     $('#output').html(data);


               }


        });

        }) ;
});
```

In this case, i only get the result once the script has finished executing.
I'd like to see the output once in 15 seconds in the webpage ( poll once in 15 seconds). Any suggestions would be really helpful to me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: setInterval on the ajax call? Or a simple browser refresh? Depends a bit on what else the page does. But basically you can use your ajax function every 15 seconds instead of onclick.

Comment: you mean to say setInterval on the "url:'/cgi-bin/rfc.py'," ??

Answer (score 0):

A basic interval would be something like:

```
// Save the interval so we can stop it if needed by clearing the interval
let interval = null;
// Interval delay constant. 15s equals 15000 ms.
const DELAY = 15000;
// Render the output to the form.
const render = function( data ) {
    $( '#output' ).html( data );
};
// Trigger the ajax call every DELAY seconds.
const start_interval = function() {
    interval = setInterval( function() {
        const data = $('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/cgi-bin/rfc.py',
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: render
        });
    }, DELAY );
};
// Start using the interval once the webpage is loaded.
$(document).ready( start_interval );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. ! This runs my script placed in "url" run after every delay. I need the script to be run only once. and then get the result of that script after every delay. Can you help me on this ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you only do the ajax call once, the result of the script won't change.